# How to use GETH to obtain the ABI corresponding to the contract address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, go-ethereum, geth

Now the ABI code can be obtained through solc compilation or etherscan. Currently we have deployed ethereum full node, is there a way to directly obtain the corresponding ABI based on the contract address.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get the ABI JSON from just the compiled bytecode. You need the source code for that.

---

It's because of what the ABI JSON represents. It represents info on `public` and `external` functions, that you can use to calculate hash signatures of these functions.

But the compiled bytecode only contains these hash signatures. And you can't "unhash" them back to the original info objects.